# Можно ли обойтись без кавычек, называя статуи Летнего сада?

Tags: пунктуация

> Моя жизнь началась там – среди величественных богов и героев. В
>   задумчивости замирала я возле них: Аполлон, Рок, Аврора, Слава,
>   Искренность, Немезида и Милосердие, Истина и Архитектура, Амур и
>   Психея…

И ещё (кроме кавычек). После перечисления на запятых скульптуры названы парами, а заключает перечень "Амур и Психея", которая одна, -

как с этим быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Названия скульптур могут иметь две формы написания,** например: древнегреческая скульптура "Венера Милосская" (официальное название) и просто  Венера Милосская:

"Венера Милосская была обнаружена  французскими мореплавателями в 1820 году на острове Мелос".

Также: "Скульптурное богатство Летнего сада на сегодняшний день включает 92 мраморные скульптуры, в том числе аллегорические статуи Архитектуры, Славы, Мореплавания и Правосудия".

Думаю, что **при описании личных впечатлений совершенно ни к чему использовать кавычки,** характерные для официальных названий, которые употребляются в справочниках.

2) Если автор соединяет скульптуры парами (Немезида и Милосердие, Истина и Архитектура), **то это следует, конечно, сохранить:** возможно, он  видит в них нечто общее или просто привык переходить таким образом от одной статуи к другой.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, первое, что приходит в голову, это изменить порядок перечисления. Но тут это тоже не решит проблему до конца.

Потому что невозможно в рамках пунктуационных договоренностей и разумной достаточности разделить случаи и подчеркнуть одновременно, что последняя - одна скульптура. Получается, что в этом случае в последней паре кавычки необходимы, если важно, что это одна скульптура. Это же название. А в первых случаях оно не нужно, это больше имена, чем имена. Ну а если это не принципиально, пусть останется и эта парочка без кавычек. Ведь есть же в скульптуре и Амур, и Психея...

Идеально было бы избавится и от ненужных "и", заменив в двух случая союз на запятые, а амурную парочку вынести в середину списка. Разночтений не возникнет. Как-то так:

***...Аполлон, Рок, Амур и Психея, Аврора, Слава, Искренность, Немезида,  Милосердие, Истина, Архитектура***

Но, боюсь, это будет неприемлемо для автора, поскольку в заданном порядке чувствуется некая последовательность, не в смысле соответствия плану парка (у меня нету, а на память полагаться смешно), но по какому-то эмоциональному настрою.

Так что, выбирая из двух зол меньшее, оставьте, наверное, без кавычек. Ну не убудет от непродвинутого читающего от того, что он не узнает, что последняя скульптура - парная.

Answer (score 1):

Вчитайтесь в текст. Автор перечисляет имена "богов и героев", изваянных в мраморе, а не названия скульптур. Поэтому нет причин подчеркивать, что Амур и Психея изображены в рамках одной скульптуры.